# Infinispan File Cache Store

Tags: infinispan

I am trying to persist the entries in cache in a file using FileCacheStore but getting the following exception

org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.start() on object of type PersistenceManagerImpl

Comment: Please, always post the full stacktrace and library versions. Also, add the configuration part.

Comment: did you solved the issue? could you share your Inifinispan configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You've initialized a cache with persistence. Make sure that you have read/write permissions to the cache file.

This means that if your persistent cache files are initialized or located under `/var/cache` then the user which starts the server has to own the directory or have read/write permissions for it. If you're using a cluster make sure that all cluster users have access to this path.