# How to solve org.infinispan.commons.CacheException?

Tags: caching, infinispan

I have seen the solution specified in the link below, and I don't get a solution for that error.

[Infinispan File Cache Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746606/infinispan-file-cache-store)

This is the message in my stacktrace,

```
org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: 
Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.start() on object of type PersistenceManagerImpl

Caused by: 
org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: 
Unable to start cache loaders

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
at org.infinispan.commons.util.SecurityActions.lambda$invokeAccessibly$0(SecurityActions.java:79) ~[infinispan-commons-9.3.5.Final.jar:9.3.5.Final]
... 190 common frames omitted
```

Please suggest me a better solution.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You skipped the interesting part of the exception. However I suspect this is related to Java 11. Upgrade to Infinispan 9.4.8.Final and try again please.

Comment: StackOverFlow doesn't allow me to paste full stacktrace. Thats the reason for me to skip and I am using java 10 not 11, so can you please tell the version number of infinispan for java 10?

Comment: I will try to paste half of my stacktrace atleast. @Tristan Tarrant

Comment: My pom.xml file is as follows, Whether i need to do anything in this?

Comment: Use the Infinispan forum https://developer.jboss.org/en/infinispan/content or the chat https://infinispan.zulipchat.com
Are you aware that Java 10 is EOL and you should upgrade to Java 11 ?